# MySQL Query to find rows less that a fiscal year in the form YYYY-YYYY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `table_lists` like this [![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
 1. 2018-2019
 2. 2019-2020
 3. 2017-2018
 4. 2019-2020
 5. 2018-2019
 6. 2019-2020
```

Now I need to display results where acad_yr is less than a give acad_yr like, 2019-2020 or 2018-2019.

I tried like `select * from table_lists WHERE acad_yr < '2019-2020'`

It is showing results, but don't know it is the correct and effective method. `acad_yr` is of type `varchar`. Any better solution for this?

Comment: if oyu are sure that the entries are in the right progression based on the id you can use that instead of a varchar field to do the comparison

Comment: What is your expected result from this query?

Comment: This is fine, but I would simply store 2018-2019 as 2018, in a column called something like fiscal_year, or whatever was appropriate.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai It should show rows that of acad_yr having records 2018-2019 and 2017-2018 only

Comment: @Strawberry you are definitely right. Since the stored year spans seem to be under the form `year N - Year N + 1`, this is storing useless informations. And consuming disk space. A `SMALLINT` (unsigned ?) seems enough and uses 2 bytes per entries, when a `VARCHAR(9)` uses *at least* 9 bytes per entries

Answer (score 2):

Your method is fine.  This comparison:

```
where acad_yr < '2019-2020'
```

is executed as a string comparison.  You are using four-digit years and the strings will compare as you want them to.

Comment: I agree, however, this will work in *realistic* cases. In fictionnal cases, such as video games in example, this comparison `'2020-2021' < '10000-10001'` won't work

Answer (score 1):

Assuming  your acad_year  column content is based on a fixed pattern with a separator char  could try using a casting to int for the left side of the string

```
select  *  
from my_table 
where cast(left(acad_year,4) AS UNSIGNED ) < cast(left('2020-2019',4) AS UNSIGNED )
```

and for  fictional sample with not a fixed  length but the minus sign as separator you could use.

```
select  *  
from my_table 
where cast(left(acad_year,locate('-',acad_year)) AS UNSIGNED ) < cast(left('2020-2019',locate('-','2020-2019')) AS UNSIGNED )
```

Comment: You can do this, but why?

Comment: The cure seems worse than the illness.

Comment: @Strawberry why?

Comment: @user7282 As mentioned, because functions cannot use indexes.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `substr()` function to divide the acad_year

```
select * from table_list where substr(acad_yr,4) < substr('2019-2020',4);
```

Comment: @Strawberry any reason?

Comment: @user7282 Functions cannot use indexes, so the OP is better off sticking with what they've got.

Comment: How are exact results better than slow results ? Sorry, now I see OP has a good results...

Comment: @VBoka Exact results are always better than slow results.

Comment: @Strawberry wrong question, how are wrong results better than slow results :) hahahhaha bit I see that OP is getting what he wants, it is just the better aproach he is looking for if I got it right...